# No permission localhost/reports error for DOMAIN\USERNAME

Tags: reporting-services, permissions

I've been searching for this problem all day. For some reason I get the error:

User 'DOMAIN\USERNAME' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

when I want to go to localhost/reports with my normal user account (it is administrator).
I tried all different ways posted on the internet and it still doesn't work.

As a last resort I tried to create a new user account on my pc with admin rights. And voila, it works. I run IE as administrator and I can connect to localhost/reports.

Now, why in the world cant I connect to the report server on my main account? Obviously it is an admin and I run IE as administrator.

I realy hope any of you can help me.

Greetings

PS: also, when I try to go to localhost/reportserver i get the error:
The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\USERNAME' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Finaly found a link that did it for me:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f477018-aa14-4db0-8989-ce763b122a2a/sql-server-express-2008-reporting-services-rsaccessdenied-error?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

When SSRS stands itself up, it only adds the Builtin/Administrator to have access to the report manager.  Run IE as Administrator and navigate to the report manager page.  Then in Site Settings click on Security and add your normal user account as an administrator.  That should do the trick.

Comment: I can't get on the report manager page, which is the whole problem of my post. I can't get on localhost/reports nor on localhost/reportserver